# Grabbing totals for dynamic groups of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that provides the results of a survey 0-5 for every group in our company. I need to then put the total number of each in a column after it.

```
                             Total 0 Total 1 Total 2 Total 3 Total 4 Total 5
   Group 1   3      Group 1                             1              2
   Group 1   5      Group 2                                            2
   Group 1   5
   Group 2   5
   Group 2   5
```

So, the list on the left will be different every day but the list of groups for the totals will be static and alphabetic listing the totals from the list on the left.

I'm not sure this can be done without some VBA and possibly even dumping data out and back in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be accomplished using regular Excel formulas. Please consider the following formula placed on `F2` representing "Group 1" with "Total 0" results:

```
{=SUM(IF(IF($E2=$A$2:$A$577,$B$2:$B$577,"")=VALUE(RIGHT(F$1,1)),1,0))}
```

Please note that the curly brackets are not typed in manually but represent that this is an array formula inputted by pressing `CTRL` + `Shift` + `Enter` after typing the formula. You can then copy the formula for the other cells in your table. Also note that the formula uses the header name to determine the values being searched for. Regards.

Comment: My columns are 
A = Group 1-576, 

B = Survey Results  

C = blank, 

D = blank, 

E = Static Group List 

F-K = Totals from B.

How would I have to adjust for this? Thank you

Comment: `F2  {=SUM(IF(IF($E2=$A$2:$A$577,$B$2:$B$577,"")=VALUE(RIGHT(F$1,1)),1,0))}` still pressing `CTRL` + `Shift` + `Enter` when inputting (don't type the curly brackets). Then you can copy through F2 to K577. Regards,

Comment: For whatever reason I get all 0s with that.

What I've done instead so far was written some basic modules that re-sort the sheet so the groups on the left are alphabetized, then a script to highlight each group one at a time, then do a count of each number 0-5 and list a total of each which then needs to be dumped out to cells in columns F-K

Comment: Well this is a bit different than the approach I was applying. If you are already calculating the results through VBA you can then output by making your results range equal the variable your dumping your results in: `ResultsRange.Value2=ResultsArray` or something to that effect.